# Highstock: Grid-lines on top of area but not breaking the chart line

Tags: highcharts

what I am trying to achieve is an area chart in highstock, where I have 1 pixel gridlines on both x- and y-axis which should be visible on top of the fill area but should **not** break the chart line.

Look at this example from the highstock api: http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/5uZzk/

Is it possible to somehow have those grid lines not break the chart line?

I already tried splitting up my series into two series with different `index`es where one would only represent the "area" (e.g. index 3) and the other the "line" (e.g. index 5) so that I could define the `gridZIndex` to be 4 which should have placed it right in the middle of the series. However that did not seem to work. Either the grid was on top of them all or below them.

I should also point out that a transparent `fillColor` for the area does not solve my problem because it makes the grid lines less visible.

So, does anyone have an idea how to achieve this?

Comment: Unfortunately in Highcharts structure is that you can have gridLines over series, or under them.

Comment: So you're saying there is no way to achieve that?

Comment: You can try modify sources to achieve that or modify DOM, but yes, this is not supported.